# Google Cloud Container Builder from Cloud Source Repository

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-container-registry

Is it possible to build a docker container using Google Cloud Container Builder from source code in Google Cloud Source Repository?

The [docs](https://cloud.google.com/container-builder/docs) say the code must be in Cloud Storage so I assume the answer is no but this seems crazy. Am I missing something? Is code in Google Source Code accessible via Cloud Storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is now publicly supported, see API docs at https://cloud.google.com/container-builder/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.builds#RepoSource

Let us know if you have any problems or feature requests or use cases this doesn't cover.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the API is fairly low level, and so building from GSR or other source control systems directly is not currently possible.

However it is possible to write a service which can watch for source code changes from your favorite SCM, copy that source into a GCS bucket (handling your SCM auth as necessary) and then trigger the Container Builder API to build an image.

Google is running an Alpha program for additional tools that are built on top of this API. Those who are interested are encouraged to [sign up here](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1qZyAitKv23aYL44dPmgr7l6bhDXV0PVVgRxR9f7e8ng/viewform).